# How can I read a string until I find a "text" in it (or somehow make the reading faster)?

Tags: java, android, string

I have a class here, where I read a source of a webpage and search for a specific value. This typically takes 1 second to be completed, but I want it be shorter. My first guess, that this value is usually at the half of the page, so I might only read the half of it.

```
public class ReadData {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
             StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder(1000000);

         URL url = new URL(url);
         HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn
                 .getInputStream()));
         while (rd.readLine() != null) {
             line.append(rd.readLine());
             }

         long start = line.indexOf(startReading);
         long finish = line.indexOf(finishReading);
         String value= line.substring((int)start + 1, (int)finish);
         System.out.println("VALUE: " + value);

        }
}
```

So now I read the whole text, then find the `startReading` and `finishReading` strings and I get the value between them. How can I read the source only till I find the `finishReading` string? Or is there any way to make the reading faster?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why did you add the **Android** tag ?

Comment: I'm going to take a guess that most of the time is probably spent connecting to that URL.

Comment: You are throwing away half of the lines. Just use one rd.readLine();

Answer (score 2):

Your current version reads in the entire document into memory and then looks for the bit you are interested in by searching the in-memory copy.

A better way is to read the document a line at a time, looking for a line containing the start and end strings.  Only start saving with you get the "start" line, and stop entirely when you get the stop line.

Whether this will speed up your application significantly depends on where the time is currently being spent.  If most of the (wall clock) time is in starting the JVM, sending the request and waiting for the document to start arriving this won't help much.  Similarly, it won't help if the text between the "start" and "end" is most of the document.

---

A couple of other notes:

1. Your program as written will be discarding the newlines in the input.  If it is text, that could result in consecutive words being concatenated across line boundaries.
2. You don't close the Reader at the end, and that you lead to a resource (file descriptor) leak.
3. Preallocating a huge StringBuilder is probably a bad idea ... unless you have a good estimate of how big it needs to be.

Comment: Thank you very much for your notes, I somewhere read that preallocating the StringBuilder makes the reading faster, but it didnt have an impact on it, so I will remove it.

Comment: @JaniBela - preallocating is a good idea if you have a good estimate of how big the buffer needs to be.  But preallocating a randomly large buffer is a bad idea.  What you are doing is allocating a large `char[]`, and the elements in that array all need to be set to their default values.  In your case, a million of them!

Answer (score 0):

```
while (rd.readLine() != null) {
    String temp=rd.readLine() ;
    line.append(temp);
    if(temp.contains(finishReading))
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I already tried it, but it didnt get faster by using this.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a smaller period of time, you can check / search for the text during the file reading. It honestly depends if the original text has no new lines at all (the performance will be the same if this is the case).

But before tackling that, I believe that you are reading from your URL the wrong way ! You are calling the method **readLine ()** twice while adding the string during the second call !! So you are skipping a line during each iteration !

It believe that it should be done this way :

```java
public class ReadData {

    public static void main ( String [] args ) throws IOException {

        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder ();

        URL url = new URL ( url );
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection ();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader ( conn.getInputStream () ) );

        String line = null;
        while ( ( line = rd.readLine () ) != null ) {
            text.append ( line );
            text.append ( "\n" );
        }

        rd.close ();

    }
}
```

Now to search for the text value that you need which is between **startReading** and **endReading** , you can do it this way :

```
public static void main ( String [] args ) throws IOException {

    // Calendar object used to know when the iteration started
    Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance ();
    SimpleDateFormat displayDate = new SimpleDateFormat ( "HH:mm:ss SSS" );
    System.out.println( "Iteration started at : " + displayDate.format ( start.getTime () ) );

    String line = null;
    boolean startReadingFound = false;
    boolean endReadingFound = false;
    while ( ( line = rd.readLine () ) != null ) {
        text.append ( line );
        text.append ( "\n" );

        // Check if 'startReading' is previously found
        if ( startReadingFound == false ) {
            // Search for the 'startReading' string
            int startIndex = line.indexOf ( startReading );
            if ( startIndex != -1 ) {
                // 'startReading' found
                startReadingFound = true;
                // Search for the 'endReading' string, it may be on the same line
                int endIndex = line.indexOf ( endReading );
                if ( endIndex == -1 ) {
                    // 'endReading' not found
                    value.append ( line.substring ( startIndex + startReading.length () ) );
                    value.append ( "\n" );
                }
                else {
                    // 'endReading' found
                    endReadingFound = true;
                    value.append ( line.substring ( startIndex + startReading.length () , endIndex ) );
                    value.append ( "\n" );
                }
            }
        }
        // Check if 'endReading' is previously found
        else if ( endReadingFound == false ) {
            // Search for the 'endReading' string
            int endIndex = line.indexOf ( endReading );
            if ( endIndex == -1 ) {
                // 'endReading' not found
                value.append ( line );
                value.append ( "\n" );
            }
            else {
                // 'endReading' found
                endReadingFound = true;
                value.append ( line.substring ( 0 , endIndex ) );
                value.append ( "\n" );
            }
        }
    }

    rd.close ();

    // Calendar object used to know when the iteration ended
    Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance ();
    System.out.println( "Iteration ended at : " + displayDate.format ( end.getTime () ) );
    System.out.println( "Iteration duration : " + ( end.getTimeInMillis () - start.getTimeInMillis () ) + " milliseconds." );

}
```

As you can see, first of all you can start looking for the **startReading** string in each line. If you find it, you start adding (after the start reading string) the lines till you find the **endReading** string.

In order to know the exact time spent in the while loop, I have added calendar objects that I am displaying, so you can know the exact duration in milliseconds.

Try it and let me know if it solved your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your code, I am going to try it asap. But I am suprised if I really miss every other rows.

Comment: Yes you were during each iteration, retrieving 2 lines : you were skipper the first and storing the second. Each time you call **rd.readLine ()**, you retrieve a new line.